# SQL Server stats and indexes after a partition swap

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

This question might be a bit too general but I thought I would ask. I'm working with a terabyte scale data warehouse in SQL Server 2008 R2. There is a large fact table with data going back 5 years. I have aggregated a lot of this old data to a different table at a higher level of granularity. The next step is to remove the old data from my fact table.

I've decided that partition swapping is probably the best way to go to remove the older rows from the fact table and put them  in an archive table, but I was wondering what a partition swap will do to stats and indexes on my fact table? Should I consider manually updating statistics after a partition swap? (auto update is set to off), will my indexes be fragmented and need reorganising or rebuilding?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partition switching is a metadata operation, so it's not going to cause fragmentation as no physical data is actually moving-- just logical references to it.

You should probably be updating statistics on a large table regularly, but it's not especially needed after a partition switch.